# Method for Decrypting Old Abi-Coder Files?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, encryption-symmetric

I have an old file I encrypted with ABI-CODER when I was a teenager, to which I have long forgotten the key. I was wondering if anyone was aware of a method for decrypting the file?

Answer (score 1):

You best bet is to try possible keys that the younger you might have thought of: "password", "secret", etc.  Abi-Coder uses 3DES, AES or Blowfish so it is probably not breakable any other way. There are password cracker programs available that try different likely combinations: "password", "passw0rd", "password1" etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, "younger me" used a pretty complex password (I still remember most of it.) :-/